# How to tunnel Linux X-Windows over the internet?

Tags: linux, x-windows

I'd like to display GUI apps running on one Linux box on another machine.

I already do this with local machines, but how to do this over the internet?

Update: I'm already using ssh to access the machine over the internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you stated that you are already doing this with local machines, I assume you already know about using `ssh -X`. One addition might be to use the `-C` parameter for enabling compression.

In order to use this over the Internet, you just need to make sure your other machine is accessible - i.e. you need to know the IP or hostname (in case of a dynamic IP, you can use a dynamic DNS provider like http://dyn.com) and make sure the SSH port (can be different from 22) is accessible from the outside.

For a typical "home" server, you would most likely need to set up port forwarding at the router to have the SSH request forwarded to your server.

Comment: Thanks @BennyB I didn't know about -x. I'm using putty which has an X11 forwarding option, I'll make use of that instead. I didn't realise that the option was already set in putty for me for local machines.

Comment: @Craig: Upper/lowercase is significant! `ssh -x` does the COMPLETE OPPOSITE (disables X forwarding) of `ssh -X` (which enables X forwarding)

Answer (score 2):

You need to login to the remote machine with X11 forwarding.

You can do this by using the -X parameter when you login

```
ssh -X user@server
```

Once logged in, run any X program on `server` and that program's window will appear on your local machine. It doesn't matter if `server` is a machine on the local network or a machine on the other side of the world accessed over the Internet

`ssh man` will give you a little more information on the -X switch:

```
 -X      Enables X11 forwarding.  This can also be specified on a per-host
         basis in a configuration file.

         X11 forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the
         ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the
         user's X authorization database) can access the local X11 display
         through the forwarded connection.  An attacker may then be able
         to perform activities such as keystroke monitoring.

         For this reason, X11 forwarding is subjected to X11 SECURITY
         extension restrictions by default.  Please refer to the ssh -Y
         option and the ForwardX11Trusted directive in ssh_config(5) for
         more information.
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to look into FreeNX: http://freenx.berlios.de/ :)